# Group Selenium Nodes together

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I am using selenium-server-standalone V3.141.59, I have 1 hub and 4 nodes, I need to group each 2 nodes together, so I can run on a specific group.

How I can do that? is there any capability for that.

I tried nodeGroup, group, grid.nodeGroup, nothing worked.

I need to run it from command line without .json file.

Comment: you can make use of the --hubConfig option along with a JSON configuration file. Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in capability to group nodes directly from the command line without using a configuration file. you may want to check out this link https://www.inviul.com/selenium-grid-commandline/

Comment: ok how to group them using json file

Comment: added in the answer, try this let me know if you have any further questions

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file named `grid-config.json` (or any other name you prefer) and open it in a text editor.
2. Add the following content to the file:

```json
{
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets": [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {},
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "registry": "org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "role": "hub",
  "debug": false,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "timeout": 1800
}
```

3. Save the file.

To create node groups, you'll need to modify the configuration file:

1. Open the `grid-config.json` file in a text editor.
2. Add a `"nodePolling"` key at the end of the file with the desired configuration. For example:

```json
{
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets": [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {},
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "registry": "org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "role": "hub",
  "debug": false,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "timeout": 1800,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "nodePollingConfig": {
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
    "nodePollingTimeout": 5000
  }
}
```

3. Save the file.

Now, you can start the hub and nodes using the modified configuration file:

1. Open a terminal or command prompt.
2. Navigate to the directory where the `selenium-server-standalone` JAR file is located.
3. Start the hub using the following command:

   ```bash
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -hubConfig grid-config.json
   ```
4. Start the nodes using the following command:

   ```bash
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig grid-config.json
   ```